# Merging two identical modules in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Could help me merge these two modules, so I can use them more than only one time?

**First module:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
Dim ultimaLin As Long, area As New Collection
Dim Value As Variant, temp() As Variant

On Error Resume Next
  
ultimaLin = Sheets("DBTemp").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
temp = Sheets("DBTemp").Range("A2:A" & ultimaLin).Value

For Each Value In temp
If Len(Value) > 0 Then area.Add Value, CStr(Value)
Next Value

For Each Value In area

titulo_livro.AddItem Value

Next Value

Set area = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Second module:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ultimaLin As Long, area As New Collection
Dim Value As Variant, temp() As Variant

On Error Resume Next
  
ultimaLin = Sheets("DBTemp").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
temp = Sheets("DBTemp").Range("B2:B" & ultimaLin).Value

For Each Value In temp
If Len(Value) > 0 Then area.Add Value, CStr(Value)
Next Value

For Each Value In area

autor_livro.AddItem Value

Next Value

Set area = Nothing

End Sub
```

As you can see it, they are basically the same thing, but in the second one I want to reproduce the obtained result in another range.

Thanks!

Comment: So put this code in a `sub Initialize(byval Column as string)`, use the `Column` instead of the A or B, and call `Initialize "A"` and `Initialize "B"` from the respective `UserForm_Initialize`s?

Comment: Also need to pass in a different control to populate - `titulo_livro` vs. `autor_livro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor out the common parts of the code into re-usable methods.

Example Form module code:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DBTemp")
        FillFromRange .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), _
                      titulo_livro
    End With 
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```vb
Sub FillFromRange(rng As Range, ctrl As Object)
    Dim v
    For Each v In UniquesFromRange(rng)
        ctrl.AddItem v
    Next v
End Sub

Function UniquesFromRange(rng As Range)
    Dim col As New Collection, data, v
    data = rng.Value
    For Each v In data
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add v, CStr(v)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next v
    Set UniquesFromRange = col
End Function
```